# How does Spring Session support multiple sessions within a single browser?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-session

The Spring Session documentations describes as one of its usage benefits as written below.

> Allowing for a single browser to have multiple simultaneous sessions in a transparent fashion. For example, many developers wish to allow a user to authenticate with multiple accounts and switch between them similar to how you can in gmail.

Technically, how does one leverage that benefit, how is it implemented?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Spring Session RC1, Spring Session will keep track of all the Sessions in a single cookie. Using a pattern like this:

```
0 defaultsession alias sessionid alias2 sessionid2
```

Then you can select which session you are actively using by ensuring that you have the query parameter of "_s" with the value of the alias. For example, requesting the URL /index?_s=alias2 would use sessionid2. If _s is undefined, then the session alias of 0 is used. This means /index would result in using default session. You can find this documented on [CookieHttpSessionStrategy](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/9834e91c6d99d477a5499d1474e4971bc6dbf72f/spring-session/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/http/CookieHttpSessionStrategy.java)

For a working example, see the [users sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/9834e91c6d99d477a5499d1474e4971bc6dbf72f/samples/users).